# Use the code generated from postman (Python Requests) and insert that into a python script

Tags: python, http, python-requests, postman

I know that the API Call works in Postman but when I try using the code generated by Postman for Python Requests code, it does not work. I am fairly sure that the problem is in the payload formatting but I can not see it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.logmycalls.com/services/uploadCall"

payload = "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"\r\n\r\n***SecretAPIKey***\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_secret\"\r\n\r\n***SecretKey***\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ouid\"\r\n\r\n48544\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"; filename=\"Ch6WA1WgGTpI4GbI.wav\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/x-wav\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"calldate\"\r\n\r\n2015-07-01 12:00:00\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"caller_id\"\r\n\r\n8888888888\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ringto_number\"\r\n\r\n8888888888\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mine_call\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--"

headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: When you say does not work , what does it give instead?

Comment: it says successful but does not upload the file

Comment: And yet when I run it directly from postman it works fine.

Comment: Which file? The audio part is missing the audio data.

Comment: Postman got back with me that they know their code does not work. I had to recreate using python requests and it worked. Too bad we can not use the code generated by postman. Thanks all

Comment: What needed to be changed in Python to make it work?

Comment: @Lochdonan How do you format the code of postman a request library of python, I have same issue ;(

Comment: OP if you could answer your own question it would be appreciated.